# reinterpret_cast - A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type

Tags: c++, c++11

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type.

They are not talking about structs and classes here, so they are not included?

They also mean that if I have an object of an enum like `MyEnum obj;` then `obj` can be converted to `MyEnum *obj;`?

Comment: it says plainly that integral and enums can be converted to pointers. Integral values are just integers, Enumerations are just integers and pointers are just integers, thus you can convert one to the other.

Comment: Enumetration do not mean enum? `enum Color { red, green, blue };`? @Andy This in an integer?

Comment: Yes -- that's what i mean. Enum is just short for Enumeration. in your example, red, green, blue will translate to 0,1,2 in code.

Comment: You could do this as well: `enum Color { red = 4, green = -1, blue = 89 };`

Answer (score 1):

> They are not talking about structs and classes here, so they are not included?

Correct. This will probably make more sense after addressing:

> They also mean that if I have an object of an enum like `MyEnum obj;` then `obj` can be converted to `MyEnum *obj;`?

No, the enum does not become a pointer to itself. It means that if `obj` is an enum whose underlying value is `42`, then `reinterpret_cast` can convert that to a pointer to memory location `42`, and you can claim that any type of object you want resides there. On most systems, memory location `42` is invalid, but you can still convert with something like `SomeObject * ptr = reinterpret_cast<SomeObject *>(obj)`. Trying to de-reference this pointer to memory location 42 is likely to cause a crash.

The usefulness of this conversion comes when either an integer needs to be transmitted via an API that takes only pointers (not 100% reliable), or the integer holds the result of converting a valid pointer to the integer type. In the latter case, the cast you asked about becomes the inverse operation, restoring the original pointer.